# How To Properly Sort This By Date? (With Image)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, ms-access-2010, oledb

[image]

The table's name is **tblFuelTransactionLogs**, and the data I'm summing up is **Price**.
The query I use to populate the fields which works just fine in the report is:

```
MyCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Price, Created_Date FROM tblFuelTransactionLogs" & _
"WHEREYear(Created_Date)='" & year & "' and Month(Created_Date)='" & month & "'"
```

The formula I use for the "$60" is just:

> Sum ({tblFuelTransactionLogs.Price})

How do I filter the summation by date?
Any ideas will be very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Ok problem I see is simple...

1.Don't take the formula as `Sum ({tblFuelTransactionLogs.Price})` instead use only `({tblFuelTransactionLogs.Price})` and as it is place in detail section.

2.Right click the formula in detail and go to `Insert ---> summary --> insert summary in footer`

Comment: Okay I will try. But that will show $5, and $55 separately?

Comment: Okay I will display the results @Siva.

Comment: It's almost working, the $4 is missing. The display should be $5 (1 + 4) I'll try to explore more.

Comment: @Jason8 what is the result of your query? can you show?

Comment: sure. $1 -- 08/28/2014 (next line) $4 -- 08/28/2014 (next line) $55 -- 08/13/2014

Comment: group by date and place price in details then take summary in group footer and report footer.